# Intercept Spotify friend-feed?

Tags: java, python, cookies, spotify, libspotify

I've got kind of an open ended question here. I'm wondering if there's a way to intercept the Spotify friend-feed data that comes into the desktop app. What I'd like to do is write a program that would let me autoplay whatever song is at the top of the feed.

I know about the Python spotipy API, is there a way I could do this using that implementation? I also know some Java.

I can also see the friend-feed cookie files on my computer, is there a way to decode these?

Sorry for my complete lack of knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

There's no officially supported way to get the Friend/Activity Feed data.

That said, it still might be possible to retrieve it, but not that I know of.

Feel free to open a feature request for the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api) (used by Spotipy) to support this in the Web API's [Github project](https://www.github.com/spotify/web-api).